# Meteor user permissions

Tags: meteor, permissions, routes

I'am trying to check the users permission (roles) in the routing (iron routing). I have a boolean property in the user which I set in the

```
Accounts.onCreateUser
```

e.g. isvalid = false. The first problem is that only username and id are exposed so I try too publish

```
Meteor.publish('userData',function() {
return Meteor.users.find({_id:this.userId},{fields:{'isvalid':1}});
```

});

In the router I check

```
    onBeforeAction: function() {
    if(!Meteor.user() || !Meteor.user().isvalid)
        this.render('nopermission');
        else
        this.next();
}
```

It works but when I debug I can see that the onBeforeAction fires three times. First time the user is undefined, second time I have a user without the property isvalid and third time I have everything. In debug I can see the screen flash with the template "nopermission" but when I run it live it seems ok. I think I have done it wrong, how can I check the permission in the correct way? I know that this code runs in client and I plan to do the check even on the server and I suppose that the Meteor.user().isvalid works without any problems on the server.
Thanks for help

Comment: Are you waiting on your `userData` subscription in your route ? ie : `waitOn:function(){return Meteor.subscribe("userData");}`

Comment: No I don't ;) Thats the trick, thanks a lot. I rush forward with my code without the correct background knowledge. Seems I should study more. I'm very grateful, thanks.